# pandas dataframe groupby and get arbitrary member of each group

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

This question is similar to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20087713/pandas-dataframe-groupby-and-get-nth-row).

I have a pandas dataframe. I want to split it into groups, and select an arbitrary member of each group, defined elsewhere.

Example: I have a dataframe that can be divided in 6 groups of 4 observations each. I want to extract the observations according to:

```
selected = [0,3,2,3,1,3]
```

This is very similar to

```
df.groupy('groupvar').nth(n)
```

But, crucially, *n* varies for each group according to the *selected* list.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically everything that you do within `groupby` should be group independent. So, within any `groupby.apply()`, you will only get the group itself, not the context. An alternative is to compute the `index` value for the whole sample (following, `index`) out of the indices for the groups (here, `selected`). Note that the dataset is sorted by groups, which you need to do if you want to apply the following.

I use `test`, out of which I want to select `selected`:

```
In[231]: test
Out[231]: 
           score
  name          
0 A    -0.208392
1 A    -0.103659
2 A     1.645287
0 B     0.119709
1 B    -0.047639
2 B    -0.479155
0 C    -0.415372
1 C    -1.390416
2 C    -0.384158
3 C    -1.328278

selected = [0, 2, 1]
c = test.groupby(level=1).count()
In[242]: index = c.shift(1).cumsum().add(array([selected]).T, fill_value=0)
In[243]: index
Out[243]: 
      score
name       
A         0
B         5
C         4
In[255]: test.iloc[index.values[:,0]]
Out[255]: 
           score
  name          
0 A    -0.208392
2 B    -0.479155
1 C    -1.390416
```

Comment: Thanks @FooBar for the quick reply. Unfortunately it does not work for me: I get `ValueError: level > 0 only valid with MultiIndex` when trying to apply your line `c = test.groupby(level=1).count()`. I think it must be due to the fact that my original data is not indexed as yours (0,1,2,0,1,2) but (0,1,2,3,4,...). Did you already group text by 'name' before applying your solution here?

Comment: @PaoloCrosetto Sorry for the late response, must have slipped my attention. Yes, I have already grouped by `name` - that is why you see `name` one line under `score` in the representation of the data: the latter is a column, while the former is an index. If you show a slice of your data, I could see how I would implement it for that - if you still have problems implementing it.

Comment: thanks. I managed to get your solution to work. I am not using it in the final script, since I have found an easier solution by simplifying the problem. Since each group has 4 observations by design, I just need to change the 'selected' list and do a simple selection on the dataframe.