# Groupby and select the first, second, and fourth member of each group?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

Related: [pandas dataframe groupby and get nth row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20087713/pandas-dataframe-groupby-and-get-nth-row?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I can use the `groupby` method and select the first N number of group members with:

```
df.groupby('columnA').head(N)
```

But what if I want the first, second, and fourth members of each group?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`GroupBy.nth`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.nth.html) takes a list, so you could just do

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': list('aaaabbbb'), 'B': list('abcdefgh')})
df.groupby('A').nth([0, 1, 3])

   B
A   
a  a
a  b
a  d
b  e
b  f
b  h
```

```
# To get the grouper as a column, use as_index=False
df.groupby('A', as_index=False).nth([0, 1, 3])

   A  B
0  a  a
1  a  b
3  a  d
4  b  e
5  b  f
7  b  h
```

Comment: Folks who are downvoting this: is this really the worst answer here?

Comment: I think it's the best answer here.

Answer (score 3):

You can do

```
df.groupby('columnA').apply(lambda x : x.iloc[[has to 0,1,3],:]).reset_index(level=0,drop=True)
```

Comment: I guess the indices should be `[0, 1, 3]`.

Answer (score 2):

```
df1 = df.groupby('columnA').head(4) 
df1.drop(df.groupby('columnA').head(4).index.values[2], axis=0)
```