# Keep the second entry in a dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am showing you below an example dataset and the output desired.

**ID number**

```
1   50

1   49

1   48

2   47

2   40

2   31

3   60

3   51

3   42
```

Example output

```
1  49

2  40

3  51
```

I want to keep the second entry for every group in my dataset. I have already grouped them by ID but not I want for each Id to keep the second entry and remove all the duplicates afterwards from ID.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas dataframe groupby and get nth row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20087713/pandas-dataframe-groupby-and-get-nth-row)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.nth`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.nth.html) with `1` for second rows, because python counts from `0`:

```
df1 = df.groupby('ID', as_index=False).nth(1)
print (df1)
   ID  number
1   1      49
4   2      40
7   3      51
```

Another solution with [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter and filtering by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df[df.groupby('ID').cumcount() == 1]
```

**Details**:

```
print (df.groupby('ID').cumcount())
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    0
4    1
5    2
6    0
7    1
8    2
dtype: int64
```

EDIT: Solution for second maximal value -s first sorting and then get second row - values has to be unique per groups:

```
df = (df.sort_values(['ID','number'], ascending=[True, False])
        .groupby('ID', as_index=False)
        .nth(1))

print (df)
   ID  number
1   1      49
4   2      40
7   3      51
```

If want second maximal value if exist duplicates add [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
print (df)

   ID  number
0   1      50 <-first max
1   1      50 <-first max
2   1      48 <-second max
3   2      47
4   2      40
5   2      31
6   3      60
7   3      51
8   3      42

df3 = (df.drop_duplicates(['ID','number'])
       .sort_values(['ID','number'], ascending=[True, False])
       .groupby('ID', as_index=False)
       .nth(1))

print (df3)
   ID  number
2   1      48
4   2      40
7   3      51
```

Comment: What if I want to keep the second maximum value of the column? So for every ID to keep the second maximum value the column number has

Answer (score 2):

If that is the case we can use `duplicated` + `drop_duplicates`

```
df=df[df.duplicated('ID')].drop_duplicates('ID')
   ID  number
1   1      49
4   2      40
7   3      51
```

Flexible solution  `cumcount`

```
df[df.groupby('ID').cumcount()==1].copy()
   ID  number
1   1      49
4   2      40
7   3      51
```